# google maps api circular radius and marker together

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I was trying few tricks using google maps api. I am trying to

- Get the lat log of my current location and zoom in on the map.

  // Getting Current Location
          Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
- Create a radius around my current location on the google map without the 'dot'. Just a circular radius around my location
- Then use Marker to manually tap on a location on the map very close to me and get the lat long.

Basically what I am trying is I need to accurately place a marker on a building near me.

I hope I made sense. Any advise will be helpful.

Thanks
Shashi

Comment: What have you tried? There are a lot of tutorials about just this out there.

Comment: I am new to maps api. I have tried to implement my requirement by following a tutorial. but that tutorial creates a blue dot of my location. I am assuming this is default behavior. I just want to zoom into my location on the map and create a radium around me. I can then work on put a marker with onmapclick.

Comment: Here is a blog post that may help you. Basically you draw an overlay, it has a dot but as the dot is a separate thing I don't think this method will make one. Good luck. http://toastdroid.com/2014/05/27/google-maps-with-custom-view-overlays/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            LatLng myLoc = null;
myLoc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());
CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLoc); //optional
                CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12); //optional

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myLoc)
                    .title("title you want to show")
                    .snippet("anything you want to show")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```